# Get excact Match array return

Tags: php, arrays, string, unicode, utf-8

I want to get Match array and match should be excact Match in another array.

```
  Array
    (
        [0] => चित्र
        [1] => माती
        [2] => त्यावर
        [3] => शेणाने
        [4] => सारवुन
        [5] => चित्र
        [6] => मातीार
        [7] => त्यावरार

    )

    Array
    (
        [0] => चित्र
        [1] => मातीती
        [2] => त्यावरती
        [3] => शेणानेती
        [4] => सारतीवुन
        [5] => चित्र
        [6] => मातीार
        [7] => त्यावरार

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a1 =  array ( 'चित्र' ,'माती', 'त्यावर', 'शेणाने', 'सारवुन', 'चित्र',  'मातीार', 'त्यावरार');

$a2 = array('चित्र','मातीती','त्यावरती','शेणानेती','सारतीवुन','चित्र','मातीार','त्यावरार');


$match_array =  array_intersect($a1, $a2);

print_r($match_array);
```

Comment: Output of my code is below.
   Array ( [0] => चित्र [5] => चित्र [6] => मातीार [7] => त्यावरार )

Comment: So what you want exactly output(desired)?

Comment: Want output of match strings in array or want to know string is available in array or not